# How would you rephrase this sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I’m not sure about the position of ***somewhere*** in this sentence:

> I lost the photo I took when I went to Hiroshima somewhere.

Comment: "went to somewhere in Hiroshima" (if you are meaning to say that you went to some place in Hiroshima). Else, "when I went to Hiroshima" would suffice.

Comment: It is unclear whether the (unspecified) photo was lost somewhere in Hiroshima, or a photo was taken (made) somewhere in Hiroshima and lost elsewhere.

Comment: @WeatherVane Post the two alternative rewrites in your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear which of these two meanings was intended:

- the (unspecified) photo was lost somewhere in Hiroshima
- a photo was taken (made) somewhere in Hiroshima and lost elsewhere

If it was the first, I would rewrite

> I lost the photo I took when I went to Hiroshima somewhere

as

> I lost the photo when I went to Hiroshima

and if the second was meant:

> I can't find the photo I took in Hiroshima

These don't use 'somewhere' at all, because it isn't necessary and it confuses the meaning.

Comment: I would propose a third option, which is IMO the most likely intended meaning: the photo, which was taken in Hiroshima, was lost **somewhere** (presumably nearby, *i.e.* in the speaker's home/car/office).

Comment: @randomhead that's a valid difference, I avoided the word 'somewhere' because sth is always lost 'somewhere' and not 'nowhere'.

Comment: True, something can't be lost "nowhere," but the addition of "somewhere" imparts a different meaning than simply not mentioning any "where" at all

Comment: @randomhead but that isn't a third interpretation really: the confusion is when the photo was lost.